# Python Regex stop on string

Tags: python, regex

So I want to search using regex for seasons which are not followed by episode number and I have the following list :

```
string = ['Fear the walking dead Season 2 Episode 9',
'Veep Season 5',
'Martine Season 2 (unknown number of episodes)',
'New Girl Season 5 Episode 16']
```

I've written this code `re.search('.+? Season [0-9]{1,2}', string, re.I)` but it seems to take into consideration the series with an episode number also.
I want it to return True only on `Veep Season 5`

Comment: Which is it: `Season` or `Saison`?

Comment: Sorry my bad. I'm going to correct it

Comment: [This](https://regex101.com/) site is great for solving all your regex needs....

Comment: I'm already using it, but I don't know if a "stop on word" regex command exists or if there is a better way to write that code.

Comment: does `^(.+?Season\s[0-9]{1,2})$` work, with `re.I | re.M`

Comment: @Prixeler using `^` and `$` to force the match to go all the way to the end of the string is likely what you need

Comment: Thank you @depperm and Aaron that worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend using `^` and `$` to match from the beginning of a line to the end. So you can change your regex to:

```
re.search('^(.+?Season\s[0-9]{1,2})$', string, re.I | re.M)
```

Answer (score 2):

From previous experience, I'd suggest not solely doing this with regex, but I've quickly thrown together the following snippet (after which no_episode_string will contain all of the ones without episodes).

For each season we match against ".*?[0-9]*(.*)", which simply grabs everything up to and including the first time we encounter a number, and then take the rest of the string, which will either be empty (if there is no episode number), or non-empty if there is an episode number.

So we just check whether it is empty or not, and if it is, then we add the whole thing to no_episode_string.

```
import re

string = ['Fear the walking dead Season 2 Episode 9',
'Veep Season 5',
'Martine Season 2 (unknown number of episodes)',
'New Girl Seasoon 5 Episode 16']

no_episode_string = []

for season in string: 
    m = re.search('.*?[0-9]+(.*)', season)
    if m.group(1) == "":
        no_episode_string.append(m.group(0))
```